# ClientError: (<Response [500]>, DeserializationError('The following field are required: detail',))

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am in the process of creating my own SSL certificates for two sites, using [certbot and letencrypt](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuxenial-nginx).

I am running nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 on Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS

I run the following command:

```
me@yourbox:~$ sudo letsencrypt certonly --webroot -w /path/to/www/foo -d foo.com\
-d www.foo.com -w /path/to/www/foobar -d foobar.com -d www.foobar.com
```

After entering my email address, I get the following error message:

```
An unexpected error occurred: `ClientError: (<Response [500]>,
DeserializationError('The following field are required: detail',))
Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.`
```

Here are the contents of /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log:

```
2016-10-31 08:19:40,090:DEBUG:letsencrypt.cli:Root logging level set at 30
2016-10-31 08:19:40,092:INFO:letsencrypt.cli:Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
2016-10-31 08:19:40,092:DEBUG:letsencrypt.cli:letsencrypt version: 0.4.1
2016-10-31 08:19:40,092:DEBUG:letsencrypt.cli:Arguments: ['--webroot', '-w', '/path/to/www/foo', '-d', 'foo.com', '-d', 'www.foo.com', '-w', '/path/to/www/foobar', '-d', 'foobar.com', '-d', 'www.foobar.com']
2016-10-31 08:19:40,093:DEBUG:letsencrypt.cli:Discovered plugins: PluginsRegistry(PluginEntryPoint#webroot,PluginEntryPoint#null,PluginEntryPoint#manual,PluginEntryPoint#standalone)
2016-10-31 08:19:40,098:DEBUG:letsencrypt.cli:Requested authenticator webroot and installer None
2016-10-31 08:19:40,099:DEBUG:letsencrypt.plugins.webroot:Creating root challenges validation dir at /path/to/www/foo/.well-known/acme-challenge
2016-10-31 08:19:40,100:DEBUG:letsencrypt.plugins.webroot:Creating root challenges validation dir at /path/to/www/foo/.well-known/acme-challenge
2016-10-31 08:19:40,100:DEBUG:letsencrypt.plugins.webroot:Creating root challenges validation dir at /path/to/www/foobar/.well-known/acme-challenge
2016-10-31 08:19:40,100:DEBUG:letsencrypt.plugins.webroot:Creating root challenges validation dir at /path/to/www/foobar/.well-known/acme-challenge
2016-10-31 08:19:40,100:DEBUG:letsencrypt.display.ops:Single candidate plugin: * webroot
Description: Webroot Authenticator
Interfaces: IAuthenticator, IPlugin
Entry point: webroot = letsencrypt.plugins.webroot:Authenticator
Initialized: <letsencrypt.plugins.webroot.Authenticator object at 0x7ff6a5901fd0>
Prep: True
2016-10-31 08:19:40,101:DEBUG:letsencrypt.cli:Selected authenticator <letsencrypt.plugins.webroot.Authenticator object at 0x7ff6a5901fd0> and installer None
2016-10-31 08:19:51,133:DEBUG:root:Sending GET request to https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory. args: (), kwargs: {}
2016-10-31 08:19:51,138:INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
2016-10-31 08:19:51,227:DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /directory HTTP/1.1" 200 280
@
```

I don't find the logged messages very helpful in explaining how to fix the problem. Does anyone actually understand what's going on - and more importantly, how to fix this?

Comment: They already know about this => http://letsencrypt.status.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **Response [500]** means that the Let's Encrypt servers responded to an API request with **500 Internal Server Error**. This is due to an error on the Let's Encrypt's back-end side. Just wait for a moment and replay the request and eventually it would succeed.

You can check the Let's Encrypt service status at http://letsencrypt.status.io/.